# NetSuite UserEvents afterSubmit is not firing

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a very simple User Event script, which looks like this:

```
define(["N/log"], function(log) {
    var exports = {};

    function beforeSubmit(scriptContext) {
        log.debug({
            title: "Before Submit",
            details: JSON.stringify(scriptContext)
        });
    }

    function afterSubmit(scriptContext) {
        log.debug({
            title: "After Submit",
            details: JSON.stringify(scriptContext)
        });
    }

    exports.beforeSubmit = beforeSubmit;
    exports.afterSubmit = afterSubmit;
    return exports;
});
```

I have created the `Script` record and then deployed it with the following settings:

`Applies To: - All Records -
Deployed: Ticked
Status: Testing
Event Type: not specified
Log Level: Debug
Execute as Role: Current Role`

and we've configured all of the audience setting also.

After deploying the script, we tried to create a new `Customer Deposit` and expected to see a log entry in `Execution Log` for this script deployment - however it appears to be empty.

We did not get any unhandled exception error either.

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: Did you try testing with Status: Released and what is the value of Audience? Can you try it by seleting the current user role yoy are testing it in?

Comment: As @Avi mentioned, deployments with a status of `Testing` only execute for the owner of the script. Try setting the deployment to `Released`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like script is attempting to run, but throws this error: `ReferenceError: "define" is not defined. (TestUserEventScript.js$15570#1) ` Any idea what this is about?

Answer (score 3):

If that's your whole script then Netsuite is interpreting it as an SS1.0 script and is giving it a different script engine.

Your script needs to start with the JSDoc comments that SS2.0 expects:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(...
```

Note you'll probably need to delete the existing script and script file before importing the fixed script file and defining a new User Event script.

Answer (score 0):

what @bknights said and try 'inlining' your returns:

`return {
            beforeSubmit: beforeSubmitFuncName,
            ...
        };`